# Running shell commands in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, shell

How do i run a shell command in asp.net ?

I basically want something like `system("netstat -an")`;

I don't want the output to be displayed to the user. Just want to run some maintenance commands.

Answer (score 7):

call `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("netstat", "-an");` as usually

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx):

```
Process.Start("netstat", "-an");
```