# Running praat script in asp.net web app

Tags: asp.net, praat

I am working on a ASP.net web application and I want it to coorperate with a Praat script.
For example I have 2 params in the web app (String text, String filename) and I want to give these two params to the Script and it just write the content of "text" into the file named "filename".
How could I manage this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I totally understand the question, but if you are asking how to run a `praat` script that writes a string to a file from a command line (which I'm guessing might be enough), having a script like this

```
# Contents of script.praat
form Output to file...
  sentence String Your awesome string with spaces
  word Filename /path/to/file
endform

# These are the same variable names as in the form
# but with a lowercase initial
string$ > 'filename$'
```

should do it. You can then run this command from the command line (if you are doing it from asp.net maybe something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395179/running-shell-commands-in-asp-net)?) as

```
praat script.praat "some other string with spaces" new_filename.txt
```